# When bash script use here-document,this script can't run with nohup

Tags: bash, hive

A script like the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
/usr/bin/hive<<EOF
select 1+2;
EOF
```

simple run like `./script.sh` is OK,but run with nohup will sticking enter hive and before sql input.

[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vq2NV.jpg)

```
nohup ./script.sh >script.log 2>&1 &
```

But if I change spript like this:

```
hive -e 'select 1+2;'
```

[It's will OK with nohup.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrREf.jpg)

Why this happen?

Comment: what will  `jobs` say while it's "sticking" running under nohup? Might it be trying console output?

Comment: under nohup It will be console output some hive start logs,but no sql run.

Comment: sorry I mean what status (of your nohup'ped process) the command `jobs` prints out

Comment: you mean `nohup` exit code？if you want see script.log what prints out. [sticking here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vq2NV.jpg) and [success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrREf.jpg)

Comment: please show the output of  `jobs` right after you started the nohup...

Comment: [jobs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5iVYj.png)